# sidekiq runs in bursts on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, redislabs

In development, it runs as I would expect it, having 5 threads (limited at the moment due to redis connection limit) it averages at about 5-7 processes running, depending if the worker has to do anything or not (sometimes a worker would decide not to work, since the object it is working on was updated less than a few days ago)

[image: development]

on production, it behaves differently. It seems to run in bursts of around 400, and then immediatly reschedules the workers and waits a bit and then shoots a burst again

[image]

The workers work with facebook api (koala gem), which for this I use sidekiq-throttler (https://github.com/gevans/sidekiq-throttler)

with the options

```
sidekiq_options throttle: { threshold: 50, period: 60.seconds , key: ->(user_id){ "facebook:#{user_id}"}  }
```

I am using heroku and redislabs (free plan at the moment) with the procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5
```

and sidekiq setup:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { :url => "#{ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']}", :namespace => 'sidekiq'}
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Throttler, storage: :redis
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :url => "#{ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']}", :namespace => 'sidekiq' }
end
```

is this a known symptom for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's being throttled, as expected.

Comment: why the bursts? how can there be 400 processed if there are only 5 threads doing work?